# Is there a terminator-like terminal without the X environment requirement?

Tags: command-line, ssh, software-recommendation, terminator

The `terminator` console does not open in a base Ubuntu server as it requires an X environment. Is there an alternative that can work even without X?

I would like to `ssh` into this server machine and use this multi-window console. So far, I could only think of Emacs as an alternative, but is there anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest looking into screen and/or tmux.

Screen is a terminal multiplexer, which supports things like detaching, splitting into multiple views, multiplexing many terminals and so forth.

I do not know `terminator`, but I suspect `screen` may provide the functionality you are describing.